# LIFO Queue that drops elements off the back end of it when length is exceeded?

Tags: python-3.x, lifo

I am not looking to preserve data. I am looking for a container that contains the last N items I stuffed in it, and allows items to fall off the back end of it and expire.

```
blocking_lifo = queue.LifoQueue(maxsize=2)
blocking_lifo.put("foo")
blocking_lifo.put("bar")
blocking_lifo.put("foo') # <-- fail
```

Not the behavior I am looking for.  Instead, I'd like python to destroy what ever is in the back, and just store the two most recent things.

I also don't want to pop the head -- all I want is a LIFO vessel that has the latest element at position zero, and n elements (specified by me) that represent, exactly, the last n elements pushed in in a lifo order, with no steps or maintence by me to make the items that fall off the end of the queue fall off.

Is there a class for this kind of functionality in python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`collections.deque`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with `maxlen=2` does exactly what you want:

```py
>>> from collections import deque
>>> l = deque(maxlen=2)
>>> l.append("foo")
>>> l.append("bar")
>>> l.append("baz")
>>> l
deque(['bar', 'baz'], maxlen=2)
```